# Setting up gVim on windows

Tags: vim, windows-7, permissions

I am trying to get gVim working on a windows 7 machine and am having the following problems:

- Whenever I try to change the _vimrc file, I get a message saying that I don't have permission to save in this location. This is on my home pc btw.
- I can't seem to change the directory where the files I edit are being saved. They are all being saved to my desktop at the moment. I tried :set dir=path to where I want to save... with no success.

I wanted to run through vimtutor; however, whenever I type vimtutor into cmd, vim flashes open for a second then closes.

How do I alter the _vimrc file and how do I set the destination for edited files?

Comment: The good and bad thing on win7 / vista is that you need administrator permissions to do some things. So you should run the editor (notepad) via admin prems

Comment: What is the location of the `_vimrc` file you are trying to edit? It's supposed to be in your user directory.

Comment: @romainl: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim

Comment: Write your `_vimrc` in your user directory.

Comment: @romainl: is everything supposed to be in that directory, i.e., should I have specified it as my destination folder on install or does only the _vimrc go there?

Comment: No, just install GVim with the default settings. It is your job to create your `C:\users\username\_vimrc` and your own `c:\users\username\vimfiles\` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't seem to change the directory where the files I edit are being saved. They are all being saved to my desktop at the moment. I tried :set dir=path to where I want to save... with no success.

`dir` is the location for *swap files*, which are special backing files used by Vim at runtime.

What you want is `cd` or `lcd` which changes the current directory. Type `:help cd` inside of Vim for more info.

> How do I alter the _vimrc file and how do I set the destination for edited files?

I have _vimrc in my Vim folder ($VIM), so when I want to put Vim on a new Windows machine I just copy my entire folder.

Answer (score 11):

I find many people do it differently.  Here's how I organize my configurations on windows.

- First note that I don't believe in mixing my vim configurations with the stock vim installation. So I don't write or modify files in `%PROGRAMFILES%` or `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%`.
- My vim configurations work on different platforms (OS X, linux, windows). And I keep them organized in a `.vim` folder and a `.vimrc` file.
- Some of my windows machines have cygwin and others do not. On the ones without cygwin, I  put my `.vim` folder and my `_vimrc` file in `%USERPROFILE%`. On the ones with cygwin, I put my `.vim` folder and my `_vimrc` file in my cygwin user's home directory.
- `%HOME%` is not defined on windows OOTB, so I define it. I find `setx.exe` is easy...

  - Example: `setx HOME %USERPROFILE%` or `setx HOME d:\cygwin\home\myname`
  - Alternatively, you can add environment variables via the control panel.
- Note, you can copy/store the `.vim` folder and `_vimrc` file in `%HOME%`. But I like to keep them in a git repo elsewhere on my machine and link to them. On windows, I use `mlink /d %HOME%\.vim location_of_vim_folder` to link the `.vim` folder. And `mlink /h %HOME%\_vimrc location_of_dot_vimrc_file` to link the `.vimrc` to `_vimrc` file.
- Note, you should have write permissions to your `%HOME%` folder defined above... so this should solve your problem with permissions. (You need to be an administrator to write to `%PROGRAMFILES%` or `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%`
- In my `vimrc`, I have a bit of boiler plate stuff for windows:

  ```
  "g:my_vim_dir is used elsewhere in my vim configurations
  let g:my_vim_dir=expand("$HOME/.vim")

  "$HOME/.vim and $HOME/.vim/after are in the &rtp on unix
  "But on windows, they need to be added.
  if has("win16") || has("win32") || has("win64")
    "add g:my_vim_dir to the front of the runtimepath
     execute "set rtp^=".g:my_vim_dir
    "add g:my_vim_dir\after to the end of the runtimepath
    execute "set rtp+=".g:my_vim_dir."\\after"
    "Note, pathogen#infect() looks for the 'bundle' folder in each path
    "of the &rtp, where the last dir in the '&rtp path' is not 'after'. The
    "<path>\bundle\*\after folders will be added if and only if
    "the corresponding <path>\after folder is in the &rtp before
    "pathogen#infect() is called.  So it is very important to add the above
    "'after' folder.
    "(This applies to vim plugins such as snipmate, tabularize, etc.. that
    " are loaded by pathogen (and perhaps vundle too.))

    " Not necessary, but I like to cleanup &rtp to use \ instead of /
    " when on windows machines
    let &rtp=substitute(&rtp,"[/]","\\","g")

    "On windows, if called from cygwin or msys, the shell needs to be changed 
    "to cmd.exe to work with certain plugins that expect cmd.exe on windows versions   
    "of vim.
    if &shell=~#'bash$'
      set shell=$COMSPEC " sets shell to correct path for cmd.exe
    endif
  endif

  "Then I load pathogen... (Or if you prefer, you could load vundle bundles here if you wish )
  ```